# Overlap map created in ggplot and shapefile

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlap, shapefile, rgdal

I am trying to overlap a shp layer on a map created with ggplot, when I plot the two graphs are independent, what do you suggest me to do to overlap both layers?

```
data.shape<-readOGR(dsn="departamentos",layer="DEPARTAMENTOS")


ggplot()+
  geom_tile(data = tx_trend, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, fill = slope))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = rev(pals::linearlhot(100)), name = "ºC/10y", limits = c(0.1,0.5)) +
  #scale_fill_gradientn(colors = (pals::isol(100)), name = "ºC/10y", limits = c(0.1,0.45)) +
#  geom_point(data = filter(tx_trend, sign < 0.01),aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color = "Sign. trend \n p-value <0.01"),
  geom_point(data = filter(tx_trend, sign < 0.01),aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color = "Sign. trend \n p-value <0.01"),
                        size = 0.7, show.legend = T) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black"), name = "")+
  coord_fixed(1.3)+
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude")+
  labs(title = "Decadal trend Summer", 
       subtitle = "(1981-2016)",
       caption = "")+
  theme_bw() +
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(barwidth = 9, barheight = 0.5, title.position="right"))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell you only have two aesthetics here: `geom_tile` and `geom_point` both of which are displayed in the first plot.

Comment: They are in two different plots.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult without a reproducible example but I give it a try! So here are my suggestions:

1. Install the 'sf' package with `install.packages("sf")` and load library with `library(sf)`
2. Import your layer in sf format with `st_read()`:

> data.shape <- st_read(dsn="departamentos", layer="DEPARTAMENTOS")

3. Use the dedicated `geom_sf()` to plot your shape on your tile and point layers. You just need to add the following line of code in the ggplot() chunk of code:

> geom_sf(data = st_geometry(data.shape), fill = NA, color = "red") +
>
> coord_sf(default_crs = sf::st_crs(4326)) +

So I suggest:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_tile(data = tx_trend, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, fill = slope))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = rev(pals::linearlhot(100)), name = "ºC/10y", limits = c(0.1,0.5)) +
  #scale_fill_gradientn(colors = (pals::isol(100)), name = "ºC/10y", limits = c(0.1,0.45)) +
#  geom_point(data = filter(tx_trend, sign < 0.01),aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color = "Sign. trend \n p-value <0.01"),
  geom_point(data = filter(tx_trend, sign < 0.01),aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color = "Sign. trend \n p-value <0.01"),
                        size = 0.7, show.legend = T) +
  geom_sf(data = st_geometry(data.shape), fill = NA, color = "red") + # ADDED HERE
  coord_sf(default_crs = sf::st_crs(4326)) +       # ADDED HERE
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black"), name = "")+
  coord_fixed(1.3)+
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude")+
  labs(title = "Decadal trend Summer", 
       subtitle = "(1981-2016)",
       caption = "")+
  theme_bw() +
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(barwidth = 9, barheight = 0.5, title.position="right"))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but still have problems got this error :                          
 Error in vapply(lst, class, rep(NA_character_, 3)) : 
  values must be length 3,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 2  .                                                                                           Could you suggest another kind of method to plot my data?

Comment: As I feared, without any reprex, it's hard to help you. After running which line of code do you get this error?

Comment: In the end, in the last line.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I edited my answer by replacing st_sfc(data.shape) with st_geometry(data.shape). It should work! Let me know.

Comment: new Error: geom_sf() must be used with coord_sf() :(

Comment: O.K.  just indicate the same CRS as the other two layers I don't know which one you use : I edited the post by indicating WGS84 (i.e. EPSG code : 4326) as I saw longitude and latitude in your code. But if I am wrong, please indicate the right EPSG code. Hoping that it will work!

Comment: Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one. I tried with several EPSG 24891, 24892, 24893

Comment: It is difficult to help you with this. The three layers must have the same coordinate system, which does not seem to be the case. 
If you don't know the CRS of the two layers "tile" and "point", you can try to replace `coord_sf(default_crs = sf::st_crs(4326)) +`  by `coord_sf() +`  . This should force to take the CRS from the first layer that defines a CRS. But be aware, that the geometry of the layer data.shape could be erroneous because it could be projected into a system that is not its own.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support but in terms of the time. I export the dataframe and plotting it in QGIS :(

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you better. But it is always difficult to solve this kind of problem blindly, without having the layers at hand.

Comment: Don't worry, I appreciate it!!